# UPDATE INNER JOIN affecting 0 rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing a large list of 71,593 pages (and other columns about the pages) from our website CMS authoring environment and another table containing a list of 47,537 page paths on the published server.  I am trying to use a single query to update a boolean column called "Published" in the first table if the particular page also exists in the second table since all published pages should be in both.  However, my update script keeps saying 0 rows affected and I'm not getting any mysql errors.

I'm executing the query normally in PHP, but I've also tried in phpMyAdmin. I've never been good with INNER JOINs and haven't really worked in SQL or PHP in about 10 years, so consider me an extreme novice.

The tables each have a column called Path and all the rows in Raw_Pages_Pub should have matching values in Raw_Pages (well 99.9% do).

My most recent try was:

```sql
UPDATE Raw_Pages INNER JOIN Raw_Pages_Pub USING (Path) SET Raw_Pages.Published = 1
```

I've also tried

```sql
UPDATE Raw_Pages INNER JOIN Raw_Pages_Pub ON Raw_Pages.Path = Raw_Pages_Pub.Path SET Raw_Pages.Published = 1
```

I would expect a majority of my records to now have a 1 in the Published column, but instead none do.

Thank you!

Raw_Pages has the following structure:

```
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+---------------                                                                                                                                                             -+
| Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+---------------                                                                                                                                                             -+
| ID                      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment                                                                                                                                                              |
| Path                    | varchar(500) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Name                    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Date_Created            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Created_By              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Tags                    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Topic_Tags              | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Publishing_Entity_Tags  | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Premium_Tags            | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Content_Type_Tags       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Content_Directory_Tags  | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Robots_Tags             | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Other_Tags              | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Description             | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Last_Modified           | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Last_Modified_By        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Title                   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Published_Date          | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Template                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Color_Theme             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Redirect_Target         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Last_Replication_Action | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Last_Replicated         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
| Published               | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+---------------                                                                                                                                                             -+
```

Raw_Pages_Pub has the much simpler structure:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Path  | varchar(500) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: If you do a `SELECT` query, would it return result? Let's say something like this `SELECT * FROM Raw_Pages INNER JOIN Raw_Pages_Pub ON Raw_Pages.Path = Raw_Pages_Pub.Path WHERE Raw_Pages.Published <> 1;`

Comment: Sadly no.  Let me quickly pull my structure and show it

Comment: Even just ````SELECT * FROM Raw_Pages INNER JOIN Raw_Pages_Pub ON Raw_Pages.Path = Raw_Pages_Pub.Path;```` returns an empty set

Comment: How about trying a simple checking like `SELECT path FROM Raw_Pages WHERE path IN (SELECT path FROM Raw_Pages_Pub LIMIT 1000);` This might be a slow query though

Comment: While testing your query I stumbled across the answer.  Apparently when I did the load infine for the Raw_Pages_Pub, it included an extra line break at the end the Paths value.  So once I removed the line breaks, the INNER JOIN works.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you Peter. Wish you the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

Table Raw_Pages_Pub had line breaks at the end of the values due to a mistake in the LOAD INFILE import.  Once removed, the INNER JOIN worked fine.